# Can you import using absolute paths in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to use [this](https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1#.7gbpeoaax) tutorial for React Native, but it doesn't seem to work with React.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do this:

1. Add a package.json file with { “name”: “FOLDER_NAME” } in it to the folder you’d like to import from.
2. `import Thing from ‘FOLDER_NAME/thing’` or `import Thing from ‘./thing’`

…except when going “up” in the folder structure.

`import Blah from ‘../../../../../blah’`

In your React Native project, chances are you keep your code in a single folder, such as “app”. 
If you have a directory named “app” this is what an absolute path might look like:

`import Thing from ‘AwesomeApp/app/some/thing’`

What sucks about this is literally all import statements (or require calls, if you’re still into that) would start with “AwesomeApp/app/”, which is a lot to ask, when the alternative is simple to add a series of “../” (the key strokes are just so close together, it’s too easy).

To alleviate this pain point, you can simply add a package.json file inside the folder from where you want to import. In this case since all our code is under the “app” folder, we’d put the file here:

`AwesomeApp/app/package.json`

Then, add a “name” property to the json file with the folder name as its value (you can call it whatever you’d like, but really, that’ll just confuse people, including you in 6 months). The shorter, the better.

```
{ “name”: “app” }
```

Now, you can import using that name as a reference.

`import Thing from ‘app/some/thing’`

Comment: This makes projects even more messier than before.

Comment: I found this solution, but almost instantly moved on because of the downvotes. A few minutes later I found the same solution in a [Medium article](https://medium.com/@davidjwoody/how-to-use-absolute-paths-in-react-native-6b06ae3f65d1). 
TL;DR: I don't understand why this issue has been downvoted! :D